# how to use foursquare API in android application?

Tags: android, api, foursquare

I want to use foursquare API in my android application. 
In my app I want to fetch nearby place.

Could you please show me how to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Foursquare page for developers. They are having an API which you can use.

here: http://developer.foursquare.com/

Comment: can u plz tell me from where i will get API credentials.

Comment: You'll have to read the documents. spend some time with them. They have OAuth. google for some library. someone might have developed one, if not, build your own!

Answer (score 2):

Download the sample application from github.

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidFoursquare

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this project on github. You can learn from it ou use as a library. For now, only some methods are supported from the library.

https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android

Comment: Did you make your own api key access?

Comment: I have successfully integrated foursquare in my Project. But i don't know that i got success with your code or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work on FourSquare on Android with the integration of Google Maps V2 : https://github.com/azfaarks/Android-Foursquare/

You need to register on foursquare and change CLIENT_ID & CLIENT_SECRET in .MainActivity file and change APIKEY in manifest before getting started.

Comment: foursquare API is paid or free

Comment: Yes, Foursquare API is free.

Comment: thaq@Azfaar kabir Siddiqui