# Android: Integrating Foursquare into App

Tags: java, android, foursquare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use foursquare API in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755708/how-to-use-foursquare-api-in-android-application)

This is a question mainly for people who have used Foursquare in their applications, I understand it would seem like gibberish to others.

I'm relatively new to applications that interact with the internet, so please bear with me. I'm writing an application that lists various venues in a certain part of town. I was wondering, how can I list these venues so that if a user clicks on it, they can check into that particular venue on their Foursquare accounts. While some code would be best, I would also appreciate any tips on how to start as well. Right now, I am writing the application in java, using the Eclipse IDE for Android.

Also, if anyone has any simple open source projects integrating Foursquare, I would love to take a look at it!

Best,

Aneem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have asked the same question twice ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813225/android-using-foursquare)

You have two main ways to integrate foursquare:

1. Using the '[intents](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client)' to launch the foursquare application - while this is not really a full integration, it might be enough for your requirements
2. Using the [foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/) you can get full integration, you should take a look at the [Libraries](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries) page. If you want more examples, [one](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-use-foursquare-api-on-android-application/), [two](https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example) and google for the rest.

The examples will not really be enough, you should also look at the different API endpoints to better understand what data is returned to you in each action you take