# I need to url for the pages the user went trough ?(Android)

Tags: android, url, webview, foursquare

So the basic problem is we are using WebView to login to foursquare and after a user logs in 
the url gives me an auth. token .How do i get the urls so i can parse them and find the token.
I tried pictureListener but the last page loaded did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a library that has been tried and tested to deal with this rather than reinventing wheel?

A few example options are:

1. http://www.tinyappworks.com/api/foursquare.html - really good and extremely lightweight, just make sure you add your own AsyncTasks when making requests and add error handling.
2. https://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/ - From Foursqaure themselves

They both have their own documentation, and tend to push the access token into shared preferences. The Tiny App Works lib abstracts all of this out the way so you do not need to deal with the details yourself.

EDIT:

Also see this for other help [how to use foursquare API in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755708/how-to-use-foursquare-api-in-android-application)